# Searching through an ArrayList to find an object with a certain field value

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I have the array list ArrayList doctors which stores objects that store the details of some doctors. Each doctor has a unique id field. Is there a way to search through the array list for a doctor with a certain ID value?

Comment: Could you post the code where you create the arraylist? Perhaps this data would be better structured as a dictionary?

Comment: Sounds like you would be better off storing the data in a `Map<String, Doctor>` which would be a mapping of doctor identifiers into corresponding doctor objects. The lookup would become elegant and effective.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use streams on the ArrayList like so:

```
Optional<Doctor> getUniqueDoctorById(List<Doctor> list, String id) {

    return list.stream()
            .filter(doctor -> doctor.getId().equals(id))
            .findFirst(); 
}
```

Here you see streaming the list and filtering all doctors where doctor id equals the id you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
private static Doctor queryDoctorById(List<Doctor> doctors, int id) {
    Doctor doctor = null;
    for (Doctor doc : doctors) {
        if (doc.id == id) {
            doctor = doc;
            break;
        }
    }
    return doctor;
}

// is a sample object representing doctor
protected static class Doctor {
    public String name;
    public int id;
}
```

Comment: I think I will use this as I understand how it works. Thanks guys.

Comment: ok but please. remember to close this question if your satisfied with the answer(s)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest, but probably not the most efficient solution, I'm assuming you set up "doctors" with setters/getters for all the fields, otherwise you would use d.id instead of d.getId() but that's not a good practice:

I'm also assuming ID might contain letters and numbers and is represented as a string. If it is a number, you would use == instead of .equals

```
public Doctor findDoctorById(desiredID) {
    for(Doctor d : doctors) {
        if (d.getId().equals(desiredID) {
            return d;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No doctors with that ID!");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I used getters and setters with private field values so I would use d.getId(). My id values are int so I would use == instead of ".equals" in the if statement correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. "==" is for exact equality like numerical equality, whereas .equals is for comparing two strings.